# vBulletin API - can I pull thread, users, etc from third-party forums?

Tags: api, vbulletin

I'm trying to setup a site where I can pull hot threads from different forums, similar to an RSS feed. I've looked at the vBulletin API (http://www.vbulletin.com/vbcms/content.php/367-API-Overview) but its not too helpful. I know services like Tapatalk are using a similar infrastructure but I'm not sure if its a closed system. Do forum owners configure their site to work with Tapatalk directly or is there an API Tapatalk is using for this?

Comment: You have to configure the forum to use the API and Tapatalk, they aren't just going to give information away like that.